Embedding File Path Explorer in Open OnDemand Passenger App
How to Embed File Path Explorer in Open OnDemand Passenger App
I'm developing an app using Open OnDemand that allows users to submit their Gaussian scripts to SLURM via a custom wrapper we use at our HPC center called GBatch. My goal is to create a Passenger app that enables users to upload their G16 files, which GBatch will then parse and submit to SLURM.
For interactive apps, Open OnDemand offers a file_path form option that includes an embedded file path explorer and selector. I would like to use this existing functionality in my Passenger app to avoid reinventing the wheel. It seems the modals source code is located here.
My Development Stack:

HTML
ERB
JQuery
Bootstrap

My Questions:

Is it possible to embed or add the file_path form option/modal from Open OnDemand's interactive apps into my Passenger app?
If so, what are the steps or required code snippets to integrate this feature?

What I Tried
I tried making it an interactive app, but I couldn't achieve the desired workflow. The interactive apps in Open OnDemand seemed to immediately submit the job to SLURM, whereas I need to submit the G16 files to GBatch first, which then handles the submission to SLURM.
I expected to find a way to embed the file_path form option/modal into my Passenger app to provide users with a convenient file explorer and selector. However, I couldn't find documentation or examples on how to integrate this specific feature into a Passenger app, leading me to ask for guidance.
I appreciate any guidance or examples from those who have experience with Open OnDemand Passenger apps and integrating existing components like the file path explorer.
